# Clear and reuse a stringstream for multiple conversions

Tags: c++, stringstream

I was working on a Hacker Rank assignment and needed a way to convert a string to int and decided to use stringstream(my first time using it). Is there a way to somehow use the same declared stringstram(is that how you call it?) instead of creating new ones for each conversion? I tried using the .clear() function and it still didn't work.

How I did it:

```
stringstream s0(hour); // this is my way of converting string to int because stoi doesn't seem to work
s0 >> i_hour;
cout << i_hour << endl;
stringstream s1(minute);
s1 >> i_minute;
stringstream s2(second);
s2 >> i_second;`
```

and how I wanted to do it:

```
stringstream ss(hour);
ss >> i_hour;
ss.clear();
ss << minute;
ss >> i_minute;
```

is there any way to do it similarly? Looks really messy to keep declaring new ones.

Comment: Even better: `std::stoi`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the `str(s)` method to initialize an `std::istringstream` to a new string. You should use `std::istringstream` if all you're doing is converting from a string.

If the previous conversion resulted in an error you will also need `clear()`, to clear its error state.

So your example would be:

```
istringstream ss(hour);
ss >> i_hour;
ss.clear();
ss.str(minute);
ss >> i_minute;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ss.str("");
```

to clear the stream. `ss.clear()` resets only the flags.

Comment: @Arūnas: Ups, yes, double post :-)